# Set operations on a series

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm wondering if someone can help me come up with a solution to a problem; I basically have a pandas series of lists (space delimited) which I've created using pandas' string operations on series - `str.split(' ')`. I need to create another series of lists which is an intersection of each of those lists with another list.

I believe apply() to be the missing piece here, but my usage must be incorrect as I'm receiving an error. Using set operations in apply() isn't really covered by the pandas manual, but I think it should be do-able?

Basically, I have a set of events (evector), and want to set up a vector of which events share users with a given event (e2).
These have been my approaches so far:

**Original attempt:**

```
evector = attendframe.yes.str.split(' ') #creates the series of lists

e2 = [attendframe.yes[attendframe.event==686467261]] #just for testing - returns [0
  #  1975964455 252302513 4226086795 3805886383 142...
  #Name: yes]

sharedvector = evector.apply(lambda x: [n for n in [x] if n in e2]) # the important bit

print sharedvector
```

**Error:** *Arrays were different lengths: 1 vs 7*

I narrowed the issue down to the following line: 
`evector = attendframe.yes.str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: set([x]))`

I then made several more attempts to get it right.

**Attempt 1**

```
evector = attendframe.yes.str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: set([x]))
#Unhashable type "list"
```

**Attempt 2**

```
evector = attendframe.yes.str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: set(x))
#TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

**Attempt 3** (credit to Andy Hayden)

```
evector = attendframe.yes.str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: x
                                                if isinstance(x, float)
                                                else set(x))

e2 = set([2394228942, 2686116898, 1056558062, 379294223])
sharedvector = evector.apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, float) else x.intersection(e2))
sharedvector.dropna())
#works, but returns empty arrays.
```

And here is a sample the data itself causing the issue:

```
print attendframe.yes.str.split(' ')

0     [1975964455, 252302513, 4226086795, 3805886383...
1     [2394228942, 2686116898, 1056558062, 379294223...
2                                                   NaN
3                                                   NaN
```

If it is of any relevance to the final solution, I'd eventually like to create a dataframe whose margins contain events and whose cells contain a list of users shared between any two given events. Generating the column vectors is the first part of that, then I hope to run a similar apply() step across the function to create the full matrix.

Comment: Hi Andy I don't think so,  I'm not at my computer now to check, but from memory it either gave me an error stating that floats weren't iterable or that the type wasn't hashable. Will confirm this evening!

Comment: Hi Andy, as I suspected, I get back "'float' object is not iterable".

Comment: Hi Andy, I've just added in the first few rows before I saw your comment, does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking about set operations, why not use [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) objects:

```
evector = attendframe.yes.str.split(' ').apply(set)
e2 = set(attendframe[attendframe.event==686467261]]['yes'])
```

and apply set intersection:

```
sharedvector = evector.apply(lambda x: x & e2)
```

If your data has `NaN` you can wrap each set call to test if it's a float:

```
evector = df.yes.str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: x
                                                if isinstance(x, float)
                                                else set(x))
e2 = set(attendframe[attendframe.event==686467261]]['yes'])
sharedvector = evector.apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, float) else x & e2)
```

Comment: This one also gives me back an error of "float is not iterable" unfortunately. It doesn't seem to help if I place [] around the operation either: evector = [attendframe.yes.str.split(' ')].apply(set) because apparently list objects don't have an apply() function.

Comment: So NaNs count as floats in numpy/pandas parlance? 

I cleaned up your code a bit:`evector = attendframe.yes.str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: x
                                                if isinstance(x, float)
                                                else set(x))
e2 = attendframe[attendframe.event==686467261]['yes'].apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, float) else set)
sharedvector = evector.apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, float) else x & e2)`    
`"unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'set' and 'Series'"`

Comment: @analystic there's not *that* many [gotchas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/gotchas.html), but yep, that's one!

Comment: Sorry, struggling with formatting the code in comments...   
I cleaned up your code a bit:  
`evector = attendframe.yes.str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, float) else set(x)) e2 = attendframe[attendframe.event==686467261]['yes'].apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, float) else set) sharedvector = evector.apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, float) else x & e2)`  
still getting an error: "unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'set' and 'Series'"

Comment: That was a bug, sorry about that, e2 should be a set, edited. Sorry about this messing around!

Comment: I'm glad its not just me having trouble! The new code throws no errors, but appears to just return a series of empty sets? I'm trying to verify whether this is correct (because none of the sets overlap in the data) or is a bug... It does appear to be a bug though, based on some test data that I've tried it with...

Comment: This is the code I'm using  
`vector = attendframe.yes.str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: x
                                                if isinstance(x, float)
                                                else set(x))
e2 = set([2394228942, 2686116898, 1056558062, 379294223])
sharedvector = evector.apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, float) else x.intersection(e2))
sharedvector.dropna()`

Comment: @analystic that'll be because they're strings in vector but floats/integers in e2 (`'1'  != 1`)...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25225/discussion-between-analystic-and-andy-hayden)